# c++ ifstream fail() flag is on but no error shown by strerror()

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I had code like below. I feel like the file stream didn't reach the file end, because `ln_cnt` value isn't equal to the feature count (i.e. number of polyline features) shown in QGIS.

Such inequality happend when the shapefile is large so I can't count features one by one, but I used small-sized shapefile for test already and my code works well.

```
polyline_class line_1;

int ln_cnt ++; // the counter for counting the lines that's read

ifstream reader("some_polyline.shp", ios::in | ios::binary);

while (!reader.eof()){

    shp_read_pnt(&reader, &line_1);
    ln_cnt ++;

}

cout << ".good() = " << reader.good() << "\n";
cout << ".bad() = " << reader.bad()   << "\n";
cout << ".fail() = " << reader.fail() << "\n";
cout << ".eof() = " << reader.eof()   << "\n";
cerr <<  "Error: " << strerror(errno);
reader.close();
```

The result is :

```
.good() = 0
.bad() = 0
.fail() = 1
.eof() = 1
Error: No error
```

Is there an error, actually ?

Comment: Probably unrelated (but hard to be sure): [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: On topic, a great many things can happen in a stream that will not set `errno` and thus have no effect on `strerror`. In this case it certainly looks like the stream hit the end of the file. Not the sort of thing `errno` is concerned with. This is discussing C, but the end result will be similar: [Does EOF set errno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601893/does-eof-set-errno)

Comment: `ln_cnt` isn't even initialized in the code you posted. You should post a reproducible example if you want useful answers.

Comment: `int ln_cnt ++;` is not a valid expression.  You need `int ln_cnt = 0;` instead

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** 'good' is not the opposite of 'bad', 'good' is the opposite of 'fail'

iostreams have two<sup>1</sup> persistent status bits that record the results of previous operations on the stream.  Both bits are 'sticky' -- they start false, and are set to true when certain things happen, and then remain true until they are explicitly cleared via calling clear()

- eof: set if a read couldn't get data to read due to reaching an end-of-file
- bad: set if an error occurred on the underlying device

The eof() and bad() functions check these bits, and fail() checks both of them (so `fail() == eof() || bad()`).
Now the confusing part -- good() checks both as well, so good **IS NOT** the opposite of bad.  Instead `good() == !fail()`.

That's pretty much it, and explains the results you are seeing.  You read to an end of file, so the eof bit got set, but there was never any error, so bad remains clear.  You have `fail() == eof() || bad()` and `good() == !fail()` exactly as one would expect.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Ok, technically the above is wrong -- there *are* potentially more bits stored (including a good bit and a fail bit), but the overall behavior is as the above explains -- the fail bit will be set when either the bad or eof bit is set, and will only ever be set when one of them is.  The good bit will always be cleared when the fail bit is set.  The only way for things to become inconsistent with the above is if the user manually sets the bits to some odd combination with `clear(some-odd-state)`, but its not clear why anyone would ever do that.  The default state set by `clear()` has (just) the good bit set.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a safe way to tell, since you obviously did not post all the code (e. g. the implementation of `shp_read_pnt()` is missing), but I will try it anyway:

The read operations of `std::ifstream` are (in general) not required to set `errno` at all. Or in other words: It may be perfectly legal for one of the read operations of `std::ifstream` to fail and still not set `errno` at all.

C++ streams usually use exceptions or the various error bits (which can be queried with `fail()`, `bad()` etc.) to signal that something went wrong. So these should be used instead of `errno`.